# What is the meaninf of "There are such things in the world as human rights"?

Tags: meaning

Does the phrase "There are such things in the world as human rights" mean that human rights can be compared to nothing else ? That they are unique ? (and, thus, that they are very important ?). I d'like to be sure to understand exactly what the author implies with this sentence.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

The author is saying simply that human rights exist, and that they are important.
The tone is a bit sarcastic. The author is using a figure of speech, saying that things *of that kind* do in fact exist, as if answering an expressed view, or policy, or situation that seems to deny their existence or importance.

Comment: One can use such sarcasm to suggest that the other person may have overlooked something, e.g. a British policeman might say to a driver, "There is such a thing as a brake pedal".

Comment: It could be an empathic statement depending upon the context of the conversation.

Comment: @MaxW I agree, if it's sharing the sarcasm with the listener.